# SortField in NEST 7.0 alpha 2 with Elasticsearch 7.1

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I recently upgraded elasticsearch to 7.1 and NEST to version 7.0 alpha 2 in my existing .NET core based application.

I am generating search request where I am using SortField class to specify field to perform sorting on.

It was working fine with version 6.X of both elasticsearch and NEST but now after version upgrade I am getting error where I am using SortField class.

var sortField = new SortField();

Error message is "The type or namespace name 'SortField' could not be found"

Please help me out in resolving issue or let me know alternative way to achieve it.

FYI. I am using SortField instead of SortDescriptor in order to specify UnmappedType.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3792) `SortField` was renamed to `FieldSort`.

Comment: It was renamed to align the naming convention of all sort types to `*Sort`